# get vs getProperty in groovy

Tags: groovy

It surprise me!

According to the document of groovy, groovy may use "getProperty" method to get the property of a object. So when I want to change the behavier of getting property on the special object, I use a category class to override the "getProperty" method. However, it does not work.
At last, I found groovy framework use the "get" method in the category class to get property, even if the object is not a map.
My question is that is it a bug or groovy just work like that.

This is the category class.

```
class DynaBeanExtension {

    public static void setProperty(DynaBean bean, String propertyName, def newValue) {
        try {
            PropertyUtilsBean pu = null;
            if (bean instanceof CustomWrapDynaBean) {
                pu = bean.propertyUtilsBean;
            }
            if (pu != null) {
                pu.setProperty(bean, propertyName, newValue);
            } else {
                PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, propertyName, newValue);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            bean.propertyMissing(propertyName, newValue);
        }
    }

    public static def getProperty(DynaBean bean, String propertyName) {
        try {
            PropertyUtilsBean pu = null;
            if (bean instanceof CustomWrapDynaBean) {
                pu = bean.propertyUtilsBean;
            }
            if (pu != null) {
                return pu.getProperty(bean, propertyName);
            } else {
                return PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, propertyName);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return bean.propertyMissing(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public static def get(DynaBean bean, String propertyName) {
        try {
            PropertyUtilsBean pu = null;
            if (bean instanceof CustomWrapDynaBean) {
                pu = bean.propertyUtilsBean;
            }
            if (pu != null) {
                return pu.getProperty(bean, propertyName);
            } else {
                return PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, propertyName);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return bean.propertyMissing(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

This is the test code:

```
public static class TestSubClass {

    private final int e = 3, f = 4;
    private final Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();

    public int getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getM() {
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestSubClass{" + "e=" + e + ", f=" + f + ", m=" + m + '}';
    }

}

public static class TestClass {

    private final int a = 1;
    private final TestSubClass b = new TestSubClass();

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public TestSubClass getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestClass{" + "a=" + a + ", b=" + b + '}';
    }

}

Map<String, String> pMap = new HashMap<>();
pMap.put("b.e", "c");
PropertyUtilsBean pu = new PropertyUtilsBean();
pu.setResolver(new ExResolver(pMap));
TestClass testObj = new TestClass();
DynaBean bean = new CustomWrapDynaBean(testObj, pu);

int c = use(DynaBeanExtension) {
    bean.c;
}
```

This is the code of ExResolver:

```
public class ExResolver implements Resolver {

    private static final char NESTED = '.';
    private static final char MAPPED_START = '(';
    private static final char MAPPED_END = ')';
    private static final char INDEXED_START = '[';
    private static final char INDEXED_END = ']';

    private final Resolver resolver;
    private final Map<String, String> pMap;

    public ExResolver(Map<String, String> pMap) {
        this(new DefaultResolver(), pMap);
    }

    public ExResolver(Resolver resolver, Map<String, String> pMap) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
        this.pMap = new HashMap<>(pMap);
    }

    private String resolveExpr(String expression) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pMap.entrySet()) {
            if (expression.startsWith(entry.getValue())) {
                String to = entry.getValue();
                if (expression.length() == entry.getValue().length()) {
                    return entry.getKey();
                } else {
                    int toTest = expression.codePointAt(to.length());
                    if (toTest == NESTED || toTest == MAPPED_START || toTest == INDEXED_START) {
                        return entry.getKey() + expression.substring(to.length(), expression.length());
                    } else {
                        return expression;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return expression;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.getIndex(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.getKey(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.getProperty(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNested(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.hasNested(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIndexed(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.isIndexed(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMapped(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.isMapped(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public String next(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.next(expression);
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(String expression) {
        expression = resolveExpr(expression);
        return resolver.remove(expression);
    }

}
```

"get" is invoked, not "getProperty"

What's more, in the real situation `DynaBeanExtension` is compiled with groovy. The construction of bean is compiled with java. Then by using `binding`, I put it into the test code which is a runtime script executed by java code.

Comment: well you could add the the code to the question and describe there what does not work

Comment: ok. I put the code to the response of the answer

Comment: no you don't.  please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30722700/edit) the question instead. SO is no forum but a QA site.

Comment: Also, please provide link for *"the document of groovy"*. If the documentation is worded in a confusing or ambiguous way, we'd certainly want to fix that.

Comment: I used `WrapDynaBean` to replace `CustomWrapDynaBean`, as you suggested, but what can I replace `ExResolver` with so I can reproduce your results?

Comment: Ok, I add the code of `ExResolver` to question as well. But it is not important. because the logic of `ExResolver` has nothing to do with `property getter logic` in groovy. it just matter with `PropertyUtils`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in the compilation itself.  Let's look at a simpler example.

```java
class Main {
    static void main(def args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo()
        foo.str = ""
        foo.str
    }
}
```

**For Groovy classes**

```java
class Foo {
    String str
}
```

If you decompile the `Main` class, you'll see it is

```
public class Main implements GroovyObject {
    public Main() {
        Main this;
        CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = localMetaClass;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
        Foo foo = (Foo)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(arrayOfCallSite[0].callConstructor(Foo.class), Foo.class);
        String str = "";
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(str, Main.class, foo, (String)"str");

        arrayOfCallSite[1].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(foo);
    }
}
```

A `.[property] =` call gets compiled to a `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty`, that in turn calls the chain `MetaClassImpl.setProperty` > `MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke` > `CachedMethod.invoke` > `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` > `[setter]`

And a `.[property]` call gets compiled to a `arrayOfCallSite[1].callGroovyObjectGetProperty`, that in turn calls the chain
`AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty` > `GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty` > `MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty` > `MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke` > `CachedMethod.invoke` > `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` > `[getter]`

**For Java classes**

If you use a Java version of the class being called, like this

```java
public class Foo {
    private String str;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

The same `Main` decompiles to

```java
public class Main implements GroovyObject {
    public Main() {
        Main this;
        CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = localMetaClass;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
        Foo foo = (Foo)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(arrayOfCallSite[0].callConstructor(Foo.class), Foo.class);
        String str = "";
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(str, null, foo, (String)"str");

        arrayOfCallSite[1].callGetProperty(foo);
    }
}
```

A `.[property] =` call gets compiled to a `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty`, that in turn calls the chain `[Class].setProperty` > `InvokerHelper.setProperty` -> `MetaClassImpl.setProperty` > `MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke` > `CachedMethod.invoke` > `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` > `[setter]`

And a `.[property]` call gets compiled to a `arrayOfCallSite[1].callGroovyObjectGetProperty`, that in turn calls the chain
`AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty` > `GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty` > `MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty` > `MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke` > `CachedMethod.invoke` > `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` > `[getter]`

**To correct your code**

As you can see from these dispatch chains, you've overridden the getter correctly (since it happens in the class itself), but if you want to override `getProperty` or `setProperty`, you have to do this in `metaClass`, and not the class itself.  The behavior you're seeing is expected.  This code demonstrates how to override each

```
class Foo {
    String bar
}

// override using setter in category
@Category(Foo)
class FooCategory {
    public String getBar() {
        println "in getter"
    }
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        println "in setter"
    }
}
use (FooCategory) {
    Foo foo = new Foo()
    foo.bar = ""
    foo.bar
}

// override using metaClass
Foo.metaClass.getProperty { String pname ->
    println "in getProperty"
}
Foo.metaClass.setProperty { String pname, Object pValue ->
    println "in setProperty"
}
Foo foo = new Foo()
foo.bar = ""
foo.bar
```

outputs

```
in setter
in getter
in setProperty
in getProperty
```

And because the `getProperty`/`setProperty` call makes the dispatch (eventually) to the getter/setter, you can prevent the getter/setter from being called at all, like this

```
class Foo {
    String bar
}

Foo.metaClass.getProperty { String pname ->
    println "in getProperty"
}
Foo.metaClass.setProperty { String pname, Object pValue ->
    println "in setProperty"
}

@Category(Foo)
class FooCategory {
    String getBar() {
        println "in getter"
    }
    void setBar(String bar) {
        println "in setter"
    }
}

use (FooCategory) {
    Foo foo = new Foo()
    foo.bar = "hi foo1"
    foo.bar
}
```

outputs

```
in setProperty
in getProperty
```

Comment: but why “get” is called?

Comment: I've tried to give a more detailed explanation on the "setProperty calls the appropriate setter" comment I made previously. Does this help?

Comment: Your explanation is very exhaustive. And now I know why "getProperty" not work, and how to make it work properly. But I still doesn't know why "get" work. In the source code of MetaClassImpl, I found when search a property, it choose "get" method to fullfill the task, but this is not mentioned in document. Is this a standard behavior?

Comment: I guess I was sleepier than I thought.  Here I gave a detailed explanation about setters, when you were asking about getters.  I've updated the answer to address both.

Comment: But you still did not answer why "get" is called. You just told me why "getProperty" is not called. And according to your answer, I can not use category to override the behavier of getting property, but using metaclass. Then is there a standard method to using category to change the behavier?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your confusion. Under the section *For Groovy Classes*, the paragraph beginning with "*And a .[property] call gets compiled to...*" describes exactly how calling `bean.c`, with `c` in this case being the `.[property]`, calls the getter. And you can use a category, you just have to use a getter instead of `getProperty` (as I showed in my first category example -- just do the getting instead of just printlning). Why wouldn't that solution be acceptable?

Comment: My confusion is the static method `get` in category class is not `getter` of any property, but groovy use it to resolve `.[property]`. And in my situation, there is no real getter method in my class, so there is no method called `getC`. The real property is stored in a wrapped object or a map.

Comment: But you do have a getter in your category, right? That was the one I was proposing you use. If you're saying calling `bean.c` causes the static `get` method to be called.  I'm not able to reproduce that behavior. What version of Groovy are you using?

    class Foo {
        String bar
    }
    @Category(Foo)
    class FooCategory {
        static def get(Foo bean, String propertyName) {
            println "in get"
        }
    }
    use (FooCategory) {
        new Foo().bar
    }

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, code in my previous comment does **not** call the `get` on Groovy 2.4.3.

Comment: I use 2.4.3 as well. If you have the source code of groovy, you can read the code in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl, line 3241. The method `isGenericGetMethod` determine a generic get method by matching its name with string "get". And you can find this code `method = getCategoryMethodGetter(sender, "get", true);` in a lot of place.

Comment: Could you edit your example so I can reproduce the behavior you're seeing without a dependency on classes I don't have (`CustomWrapDynaBean` and `ExResolver`)?  As I mentioned in my previous comment, I don't see that my version of `public static def get(DynaBean bean, String propertyName)` (`static def get(Foo bean, String propertyName)`) is invoked.

Comment: You can use `WrapDynaBean` to replace `CustomWrapDynaBean`. I just extend it. `WrapDynaBean` is the class in libaray commons-beanutils. It implements the interface `DynaBean` which defined in commons-beanutils too. So my category is writen on `DynaBean`. The groupid of commons-beanutils is "commons-beanutils", artifactId is "commons-beanutils" as well. The version is "1.9.2". And I will edit the quesion to give the code of `TestClass`.