# Is it possible to add GroovyObject methods through a category?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy in Action, 2nd Edition published in 2015 in chapter 8.4.5 they say that categories can be used to add `GroovyObject` methods:

> Category method names can well take the form of property accessors
>   (pretending property access), operator methods, and **GroovyObject
>   methods**. MOP hook methods cannot be added through a category class.
>   This is a restriction as of Groovy 2.4. The feature may become
>   available in later versions.

which I interpreted as you can add `getMetaClass()`, `setMetaClass(MetaClass)`, `getProperty(String)`, `setProperty(String, Object)` and `invokeMethod(String, Object)` but you **can't** add `methodMissing(String, Object)` or `propertyMissing(String)`

but when I tried to add `invokeMethod()` and `getProperty()` through a category it didn't have any effect:

```
class MyClass{}

a = new MyClass()


@Category(MyClass)
class MyCategory {
    def missingMethod(String name, def args) { "missingMethod" } // GINA says no MOP hook method

    def invokeMethod(String name, def args) { "invokeMethod" } // but GroovyObject method should be fine
    def getProperty(String name) { "missingProperty" }

    def getMyProperty() { "prop1" }    
}

use(MyCategory) {
    assert "missingMethod" == a.missingMethod('a', 'b') // methods are the
    assert "invokeMethod" == a.invokeMethod('a', 'b')
    assert "prop1" == a.myProperty


    // but they are not in effect
    // assert "missingMethod" == a.method1() // MissingMethodException 
    // assert "invokeMethod" == a.method2()  // MssingMethodException
    // assert "missingProperty" == a.property // MissingPropertyException
}
```

So far  `invokeMethod`, `getProperty` and `getMetaClass` so there is only other two methods from `GroovyObject` left : `setMetaClass` and `setProperty` but since the getter versions of those don't work I suspect the setter versions won't work either. So I can't really add any GroovyObject method at all in this way.

In this other SO question:  [get vs getProperty in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722700/get-vs-getproperty-in-groovy) there is some discussion about the MOP and the only answer points to the "add method to the metaclass instead of using categories" solution. But my question is different, is it really possible or not to use a category to add `invokeMethod` or `methodMissing`?

So what is the right way (if any) to add `GroovyObject` methods via categories then?

Comment: The quote states that MOP (Meta-Object Protocol) hook methods can't be added. I'm not sure (hence not answering) but I suspect that `invokeMethod` is considered MOP.

Comment: But `getProperty` (another GroovyObject method) does NOT work either. Tried also with `getMetaClass`. So it's a bit weird that it says "GroovyObject methods" but none of them work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get vs getProperty in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722700/get-vs-getproperty-in-groovy)

Comment: In that question, the only answer just add `getProperty` to the metaclass instead of using a category, which is what I'm trying to avoid. If it is not possilble is ok but that commend in the Groovy in Action makes me think that there must be a way to add GroovyObject methods via categories

Comment: In the groovy mailing list [Jochen Theodoru](https://markmail.org/search/?q=groovyobject%20category#query:groovyobject%20category+page:1+mid:jbcyknu3parscqij+state:results)  says that adding `methodMissing` and `propertyMissing` via category should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Groovy 2.4.x can't do this but it has been added for 2.5.0-rc-3, 2.6.0-alpha-4, 3.0.0-alpha-3. So future versions of Groovy will allow redefining `methodMissing` and `propertyMissing` via a category classes. This feature was added on commit [ad664b1](https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/ad664b181249c4b8e8821003d7e750632943ce36) on May 2018 and was tracked by [GROOVY-3867](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3867)

```
// since groovy 2.5.0-rc-3
class X{ def bar(){1}}
class XCat{ static bar(X x){2}}
class XCat2{ static bar(X x){3}}
class XCat3{ static methodMissing(X x, String name, args) {4}}
class XCat4{ static propertyMissing(X x, String name) {"works"}}    

def x = new X()

shouldFail(MissingPropertyException) {
  assert x.baz != "works" // accessing x.baz should throw MPE
}

use(XCat4) {
  assert x.baz == "works"
}

shouldFail(MissingPropertyException) {
  assert x.baz != "works" // accessing x.baz should throw MPE
}
```